# How do I finish an Activity from within a mortar Presenter or a View?

Tags: dagger, mortar, square-flow

How do I finish an Activity from within a Presenter or a View in the mortar sample app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The majority of the time you would want to avoid doing this. But in dire circumstances you could follow the same pattern the ActionBarOwner[0] class implements.  Create an injectable class that exposes Activity#finish via an interface.

Item 3 in [1] is related but the calling order is inverted.  (Activity lifecycle methods to presenters instead of Presenters to Activity methods).

Hope that helps!

[0] https://github.com/square/mortar/blob/master/mortar-sample/src/main/java/com/example/mortar/android/ActionBarOwner.java

[1] [Mortar + Flow with third party libraries hooked to activity lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927990/mortar-flow-with-third-party-libraries-hooked-to-activity-lifecycle)