# How to handle onActivityResult() with Mortar

Tags: android, mortar

I am looking to integrate an application with Google Play Services and Mortar to retrieve the user's current location.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#CheckServices

This requires handling onActivityResult() in the case that Google Play Services is not available.

My first instinct on how to do this is to make `getFirstScreen()` in `Main.java` return a blank loading screen.
https://github.com/square/mortar/blob/master/mortar-sample/src/main/java/com/example/mortar/core/Main.java

After injection, during `onCreate()` perform the check to see if Google Play Services is available. If it is, then call `flow.goTo(<location using screen>)`, if not, do nothing and wait for `onActivityResult()` to be called. Then, when `onActivityResult()` fires, simply call `flow.goTo(<location using screen>)`.

The above seems slightly hacky to me. (Let me know if you need clarification). So I'm thinking the other solution might be to do something similar to this [Mortar + Flow with third party libraries hooked to activity lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927990/mortar-flow-with-third-party-libraries-hooked-to-activity-lifecycle) and hook up `onActivityResult()` to the presenter. The problem with this is that I won't have access to the `Activity` from a presenter which makes it impossible to call `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(...)` because it requires `Activity`.

I think `onActivityResult()` is very important. Perhaps it should be a part of the Mortar library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how we generally deal with startActivityForResult in Square Register.

```
public SomePresenter extends Presenter<SomePresenter.Activity> {
  public interface Activity {
    void startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent intent, int requestCode);
  }

  public final void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Make sure it's the expected requestCode and resultCode and do your thing.
    // If it isn't, no-op, someone else will handle it.
  }
}
```

And the activity looks something like:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity implements SomePresenter.Activity {


  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    // Do the usual mortar init stuff

    somePresenter.takeView(this);
  }

  @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int   resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    somePresenter.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

  @Override protected void onDestroy() {
    somePresenter.dropView(this);
    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

That doesn't help you with the error dialog, but that sounds like a separate concern to me anyway. Seems like you can use a Popup / PopupPresenter pair there. (I'm not thrilled with Popup, but it gets the job done until we have a better idea.) Or maybe the activity should just go ahead and deal with it itself? I'm not super familiar with the Play Services, haven't dealt with them yet.

Comment: Since SomePresenters extends Presenter, how do you override the protected abstract BundleService extractBundleService(V view);

Comment: I ended up implementing something similar to how HandlesBack is implemented